# Using Abstract base class type to traverse entire JAXB Object tree

Tags: tree, jaxb, abstract-class, tree-traversal

The system hardware I write software for is physically connect via hardware in a tree structure.  The data model in our application is a Tree.  For our new rewrite, we're using JAXB to create the data model.

We have three types of Devices, and they all share *some* properties, so I made an Abtract DeviceType in the XSD schema.  My three devices (Pushers, Switchers, Receivers) are all extended from the DeviceType in the XSD like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="DeviceType" abstract="true">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="atrr1" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
    <xs:element name="attr2" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="PusherType">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="pts:DeviceType">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Switcher" type="pts:SwitcherType" minOccurs="1"></xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="SwitcherType">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="pts:DeviceType">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="switcher" type="pts:SwitcherType" minOccurs="1"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="receiver" type="pts:ReceiverType" minOccurs="1"></xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Pushers have only switcher child elements, and switchers can have both switcher or receiver children.  Receivers are the end of the line (leaf nodes). xjc builds the classes.  I got the Unmarshaller to construct the object tree, but I can't figure out how to get a getter method for getDevice().  For tree traversal, I was hoping JAXB would provide something like "getChildren", but I'm not seeing in in the API. If I get a switcher object, I have the methods for getSwitcher() and getReceiver(), but no getDevice() method.  But I'm trying to avoid using *instanceof* when I do a full tree traversal.  The Java code that xjc builds, does extend from the Device class, but I just haven't learned how to get a generic getter method for all devices.  I just started with Jaxb two days ago and I have a ton to learn about the Jaxb API.

Yesterday was my first day playing with JAXB, I think this tool suits our system incredible well.  Our hardware is literally a tree,we have multiple deployments, and using XML as our site config file to build a state model would be ideal.

Any suggestions for a JAXB novice here?

Answer (score 2):

JAXB ([JSR-222)](http://jcp.org/jsr/detail/222.jsp) is the Java [standard](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/jaxb-xml-binding-standard.html) for mapping objects to XML.  There are several implementations including:  [Metro](http://jaxb.java.net/), [EclipseLink MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) (I'm the tech lead), [Apache JaxMe](http://ws.apache.org/jaxme/), etc.

JAXB is designed to map existing object structures to XML.  In your example you are leveraging JAXB's ability to generate a class model from an XML schema.  This produces something like a "typed DOM".  There will be a Java class matching each complex type (with the necessary inheritance relationships), and a property matching each attribute/element.  For example the following class corresponds to the SwitcherType complex type:

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "SwitcherType", propOrder = {
    "switcher",
    "receiver"
})
public class SwitcherType extends DeviceType
{

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected SwitcherType switcher;

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected ReceiverType receiver;

    public SwitcherType getSwitcher() {
        return switcher;
    }

    public void setSwitcher(SwitcherType value) {
        this.switcher = value;
    }

    public ReceiverType getReceiver() {
        return receiver;
    }

    public void setReceiver(ReceiverType value) {
        this.receiver = value;
    }

}
```

Unlike a DOM there are no generic getChildren() methods.  Although you could implement these yourself by modifying the object model.

**For more information on JAXB:**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/